# Bootstrap Landing Page Background

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm learning to create landing pages from good examples online. One thing I'm trying to replicate is the light background behind the words "Build fast, responsive sites with Bootstrap" on the [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) page (the angled graphic).

It's not obvious to me in looking at the page source how this is done in this example. Can anyone suggest or point to a good resource that would help me learn this concept?

My site is built with Bootstrap 4 currently and hope to be able to stay within that framework.

Answer (score 0):

The background color can be easily solved by using
`".bg-light"` as the background color class.
The easiest way to solve the shape is to draw a rectangle, rotate it to the designated degree then position it in such a way it fits perfectly woth what you want, here you can use
`".absolute top-0 left-0 translate-middle"`
and such bootstrap classes. Read more on [Bootstrap Positioning here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/)
As for the rotation, the easiest way to solve is with [Bootstrap Extension.](http://bootstrap-extension.com/#content-rotate) it provides bootstrap classes for rotating html elements. Read the docs on the link above

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `background: linear-gradient(...)`. Example `background: linear-gradient(165deg, #f7f5fb 50%, #fff 50%);` (It's what was used on the bootstrap site you referenced). You can learn more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()